# Batch go to if statement

Tags: batch-file

My if statement is:

```
If %choice%== 1 (goto 1)
If %choice%== 2 (goto 2)

:1
Echo 1
Pause

:2
Echo 2 
Pause
```

It works if I choose 2 but if I choose 1 goes to 1 then 2.

How do I fix this?

Comment: With another `goto` that bypasses 2.

Comment: So you have been onlone again a few times, but you have not yet responded to anyone who have spent the time to give you the solutions you requested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If %choice% equ 1 goto opt1
If %choice% equ 2 goto opt2

:opt1
Echo option 1
Pause
goto :eof
:opt2
Echo option 2 
Pause
goto :eof
```

or maybe:

```
goto opt%choice%
:opt1
Echo option 1
Pause
goto :eof
:opt2
Echo option 2 
Pause
goto :eof
```

a better way of doing the above would however be:

```
If %choice% equ 1 echo opt 1
If %choice% equ 2 echo opt 2
```

if more conditions needs to occur:

```
If %choice% equ 1 (
    echo opt 1
    echo do other opt 1 things
)
If %choice% equ 2 (
    echo opt 2
    echo do something else for opt 2
)
```

if only 2 options exists, use `if` `else`:

```
If %choice% equ 1 (
    echo opt 1
) else (
    echo opt 2
)
```

Then the **`BEST`** `choice` option:

```
choice /c 12 /m "Enter Choice: "
goto :opt%errorlevel%
:opt1
echo choice 1
echo do more for opt 1
goto :eof

:opt1
echo choice 2
echo do more for opt 2
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding a third `goto` location that bypasses 2.

```
If "%choice%" == "1" goto 1
If "%choice%" == "2" goto 2
:1 Echo 1 
Pause
goto 3
:2 Echo 2 
Pause
:3
```

Comment: Woah there boy... `:)` Batch does not like whitespace. `if "%choice%" =="1"` or even better `if %choice equ 1` but that also depends where `%choice%` originated from.

Comment: @Gerhard: I just copied the poster's code. That typo is theirs, not mine. I'll fix it anyway, though.

Comment: Will you Allow me the honors? :)